# Mounting partition in FreeBSD is not working

Tags: freebsd, mount

I am new to FreeBSD and I try to mount a partition `p2` of `ada1` on a new FreeBSD installation by entering:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/ada1p2
sudo mount /dev/ada1p2 /mnt/ada1p2
```

This leaves me with `mount: /dev/ada1p2 : Invalid argument` and no mounted partition. The partition scheme is GPT and I am not sure about the file system but I should be HFS+ or ext4.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is your partition really ada1p2? Isn't it actually ad1s2? What is listed in /dev?

Comment: Plain `mount` treat partition as UFS2. If you have different FS on the partition, you should use `-t <fstype>` with `mount`

Comment: @Rob: Yes, it seems to be `ada1p2`. I checked `/dev`.

Comment: @Kondybas: Using `hfs` and `ext4` as fstype leads to the message `mount: /dev/ada1p2: Operation not supported by device`. I guess I have to install support for those file systems but I could not find out how. `ls /sbin/mount_*` doesn’t reveal `hfs` nor `ext4`.

Comment: AFAIK FreeBSD hasn't native support for `ext4` yet. `HFS/HFS+` can be mounted when kernel built with `GEOM_APPLE` option.

Comment: @Kondybas: Is there native support for `ext3` in FreeBSD 10 so I just can install some port or package?

Comment: @Kondybas: Got it, `ext2` at least! `EXT2FS`, `kldload /boot/kernel/ext2fs.ko` respectively. Thanks for all your help :)